# Perl LWP Unauthorized While Curl Ok

Tags: perl, curl, lwp

I am attempting to recreate a working CURL command with LWP in Perl and I'm getting a 401 unauthorized error from LWP. The command posts JSON to a specific URL as seen in the code below. The server FQDN, IP, port and path are correct and identical between the curl and Perl as are the credentials and realm. Any help would be appreciated - thank you!

Below is the working syntax in cURL and debug output:

```
#curl -v -k -u "USERNAME:PASSWORD" -X POST <SERVER_URL> -d '<JSON CONTENT>';

* About to connect() to <SERVER_URL> port 443 (#0)
*   Trying <SERVER_IP>... connected
* Connected to <SERVER_URL> (<SERVER_IP>) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* SSL connection using TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
* Server certificate:
*       subject: [REDACTED]
*       start date: Apr 21 00:00:00 2016 GMT
*       expire date: Apr 21 23:59:59 2019 GMT
*       common name: <SERVER_URL>
*       issuer: [REDACTED]
* Server auth using Basic with user '<USERNAME>'
> POST <SERVER_PATH> HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic <BASE64-ENCODED USERNAME:PASSWORD>
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: <SERVER_URL>
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 144
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 13 May 2016 13:48:42 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 256
< 
* Connection #0 to host <SERVER_URL> left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Updated Perl code and output per Steffen's suggestion. I corrected an initial quoting error and also added the Accept header to the LWP post command:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Data::Dumper;

my $server_root_with_port = "<FQDN>:443";
my $url = "<SERVER_URL>";
my $realm = "<SERVER_REALM>";
my $json = "<JSON CONTENT>";
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 1 });
$ua->credentials($server_root_with_port,$realm,$username=>$password);
$response = $ua->post($url, 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept' => '*/*', 'Content' => $json);
print Dumper $response;

exit;

$VAR1 = bless( {
         '_protocol' => 'HTTP/1.1',
         '_content' => '',
         '_rc' => '400',
         '_headers' => bless( {
                    'connection' => 'close',
                    'client-response-num' => 1,
                    'date' => 'Mon, 16 May 2016 14:18:59 GMT',
                    'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => '[REDACTED]',
                    'client-ssl-cipher' => 'AES128-SHA256',
                    'client-peer' => '<SERVER_IP>:443',
                    'content-length' => '0',
                    '::std_case' => {
                              'client-date' => 'Client-Date',
                              'client-response-num' => 'Client-Response-Num',
                              'client-ssl-cert-subject' => 'Client-SSL-Cert-Subject',
                              'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => 'Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer',
                              'client-ssl-cipher' => 'Client-SSL-Cipher',
                              'client-peer' => 'Client-Peer',
                              'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'Client-SSL-Socket-Class'
                            },
                    'client-date' => 'Mon, 16 May 2016 14:18:59 GMT',
                    'client-ssl-cert-subject' => '[REDACTED]',
                    'server' => 'Apache',
                    'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'IO::Socket::SSL'
                      }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
         '_previous' => bless( {
                     '_protocol' => 'HTTP/1.1',
                     '_content' => '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
                            <html><head>
                            <title>401 Unauthorized</title>
                            </head><body>
                            <h1>Unauthorized</h1>
                            <p>This server could not verify that you
                            are authorized to access the document
                            requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
                            credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
                            browser doesn\'t understand how to supply
                            the credentials required.</p>
                            </body></html>
                            ',
                     '_rc' => '401',
                     '_headers' => bless( {
                                'connection' => 'close',
                                'client-response-num' => 1,
                                'date' => 'Mon, 16 May 2016 14:18:59 GMT',
                                'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => '[REDACTED]',
                                'client-ssl-cipher' => 'AES128-SHA256',
                                'client-peer' => '<SERVER_IP>:443',
                                'content-length' => '381',
                                '::std_case' => {
                                          'client-date' => 'Client-Date',
                                          'client-response-num' => 'Client-Response-Num',
                                          'client-ssl-cert-subject' => 'Client-SSL-Cert-Subject',
                                          'title' => 'Title',
                                          'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => 'Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer',
                                          'client-ssl-cipher' => 'Client-SSL-Cipher',
                                          'client-peer' => 'Client-Peer',
                                          'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'Client-SSL-Socket-Class'
                                        },
                                'client-date' => 'Mon, 16 May 2016 14:18:59 GMT',
                                'content-type' => 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1',
                                'client-ssl-cert-subject' => '[REDACTED]',
                                'www-authenticate' => 'Basic realm="<SERVER_REALM>"',
                                'title' => '401 Unauthorized',
                                'server' => 'Apache',
                                'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'IO::Socket::SSL'
                                  }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
                     '_msg' => 'Unauthorized',
                     '_request' => bless( {
                                '_content' => '<JSON_CONTENT>',
                                '_uri' => bless( do{\(my $o = '<SERVER_URL>')}, 'URI::https' ),
                                '_headers' => bless( {
                                               'user-agent' => 'libwww-perl/6.15',
                                               'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                               'accept' => '*/*',
                                               'content-length' => 144,
                                               '::std_case' => {
                                                     'if-ssl-cert-subject' => 'If-SSL-Cert-Subject'
                                                       }
                                             }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
                                '_method' => 'POST',
                                '_uri_canonical' => $VAR1->{'_previous'}{'_request'}{'_uri'}
                                  }, 'HTTP::Request' )
                       }, 'HTTP::Response' ),
         '_msg' => 'Bad Request',
         '_request' => bless( {
                    '_protocol' => undef,
                    '_content' => '<JSON_CONTENT>',
                    '_uri' => bless( do{\(my $o = '<SERVER_URL>')}, 'URI::https' ),
                    '_headers' => bless( {
                                   'user-agent' => 'libwww-perl/6.15',
                                   'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                   'accept' => '*/*',
                                   'content-length' => 144,
                                   'authorization' => '<BASE64-ENCODED USERNAME:PASSWORD>',
                                   '::std_case' => {
                                         'if-ssl-cert-subject' => 'If-SSL-Cert-Subject'
                                           }
                                 }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
                    '_method' => 'POST',
                    '_uri_canonical' => $VAR1->{'_request'}{'_uri'}
                      }, 'HTTP::Request' )
           }, 'HTTP::Response' );
```

Perl Revision #1:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use Data::Dumper;

my $fqdn_port = "<FQDN>:443";
my $url       = "<URL>";
my $realm     = "<REALM>";
my $username  = "<USERNAME>";
my $password  = "<PASSWORD>";
my $json      = "<JSON_CONTENT>";

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 1 });

#$ua->credentials($fqdn_port,$realm,$username=>$password);
#my $response = $ua->post($url, 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept' => '*/*', Content => $json);

my $request = HTTP::Request->new('POST',$url);
$request->header('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept' => '*/*');
$request->authorization_basic($username,$password);
$request->content($json);

my $response = $ua->request($request);

print Dumper $response;

exit;


$VAR1 = bless( {
         '_protocol' => 'HTTP/1.1',
         '_content' => '',
         '_rc' => '400',
         '_headers' => bless( {
                    'connection' => 'close',
                    'client-response-num' => 1,
                    'date' => 'Mon, 16 May 2016 15:41:10 GMT',
                    'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => '[REDACTED]',
                    'client-ssl-cipher' => 'AES128-SHA256',
                    'client-peer' => '<SERVER_IP>:443',
                    'content-length' => '0',
                    '::std_case' => {
                              'client-date' => 'Client-Date',
                              'client-response-num' => 'Client-Response-Num',
                              'client-ssl-cert-subject' => 'Client-SSL-Cert-Subject',
                              'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => 'Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer',
                              'client-ssl-cipher' => 'Client-SSL-Cipher',
                              'client-peer' => 'Client-Peer',
                              'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'Client-SSL-Socket-Class'
                            },
                    'client-date' => 'Mon, 16 May 2016 15:41:10 GMT',
                    'client-ssl-cert-subject' => '[REDACTED]',
                    'server' => 'Apache',
                    'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'IO::Socket::SSL'
                      }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
         '_msg' => 'Bad Request',
         '_request' => bless( {
                    '_content' => '<JSON_CONTENT>',
                    '_uri' => bless( do{\(my $o = '<URL>')}, 'URI::https' ),
                    '_headers' => bless( {
                                   'user-agent' => 'libwww-perl/6.15',
                                   'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                   'accept' => '*/*',
                                   '::std_case' => {
                                         'if-ssl-cert-subject' => 'If-SSL-Cert-Subject'
                                           },
                                   'authorization' => 'Basic <BASE64-ENCODED USERNAME:PASSWORD>'
                                 }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
                    '_method' => 'POST',
                    '_uri_canonical' => $VAR1->{'_request'}{'_uri'}
                      }, 'HTTP::Request' )
           }, 'HTTP::Response' );
```

Comment: verify_hostname => 1 should be => 0, that would match curl -k

Answer (score 3):

TL;TR: **always** `use strict` !!

> ```
> $response = $ua->post($url, Content-Type => 'application/json', Content => $json);
> ```

You've missed to quote around `Content-Type` which would have been detected by `use strict`. This result of this is a strange header `0` you see in the debug output:

```
 'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 '0' => 'application/json',
 'content-length' => 144,
```

And this also means that the setting of the content-type is wrong. This together results in the server not accepting your request:

```
  '_rc' => '400',
  ...
  '_msg' => 'Bad Request',
```

To understand what happens here look at what Perl actually sees in such code:

```
 $ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'my %x = (Content-Type => 1, Foo => 2 )'
 my(%x) = ('Content' - 'Type', 1, 'Foo', 2);
```

This shows that it will interpret the unquoted `Content-Type` as `'Content' - 'Type'`. And since subtraction is not defined for strings they will be cast to an integer, i.e. `0`. Which means the result is `0` (`0-0`).

When using strict you get instead:

```
perl -Mstrict -e 'my %x = (Content-Type => 1, Foo => 2 )'                                                                                                                                 
Bareword "Content" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at -e line 1.                                                                                                                                           
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: Steffen - I updated my code as you suggested, enclosing Content-Type with single quotes, so the resulting syntax reads 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' and using strict I don't get an error, however I'm still getting a 401 unauthorized error.

Comment: @dthumb: please update the code and debug output in your question to reflect the current state.

Comment: Updated original question with the edits as suggested - no longer seeing the malformed header but still getting a 401 Unauthorized return from the server. Thank you.

Comment: @dthumb: based on the debug output the current request returns again a "400 Bad request" (the 401 is before your authorize).  It might be that you missing some headers the server expects - notably "Accept" which curl uses. Look at the documentation of the API you are using what is expected by the client.

Comment: I appended the Apache logs from the server - the username isn't getting passed in the initial LWP POST...I'm not sure how to add that or if it's being passed already via the UA credentials.

Comment: @dthumb: This is normal behavior. Since LWP can manage multiple credentials at the same time it only sends the authorization when it receives a 401 from the server with the matching realm.  As you can see in the log files the requests with code 400 get the authorization and these are the requests which are relevant and where you need to find out why they fail.

Comment: @dthumb: Unfortunately you've removed the output of curl from your question which did show how a successful request looks like. And your code does not include the accept header even if you said you've added it.

Comment: @steffen_ullrich: I updated the latest version of the Perl and return the cURL syntax and output for both.

Comment: @dthumb: are you sure the code matches the debug output? The debug output says that you sent a content-type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (the default) while the code says different. I've tried this part of this code myself with the same version of libwww and it sets the content-type properly.

Comment: @steffen_ullrich: You are correct - my mistake. I was going back and forth between application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded in testing. The debug output is a result of application/x-www-form-urlencoded content_type and I've correctly reflected that in the source code.

Comment: @dthumb: in this case I don't know what's happening from looking at the information in your question. If you have a test site I could maybe check myself what exactly triggers the Bad request vs. successful response.

Comment: @steffen_ullrich: Unfortunately I don't have a test platform - these are production machines. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @steffen_ullrich: I switched around the source code and used a different syntax (see Revision #1 above) and I'm getting beyond the 401 Unauthorized error but still getting the 400 Bad Request.

Comment: @dthumb: this time it does not even get to the 401 because the initial request is already bad. From the debug output it looks that the content-length is missing.

Comment: @steffen_ullrich: I've got it! I switched the quoting on the JSON string and success! I had it initially enclosed with double-quotes, single-quotes delimiting the JSON data itself. Reversing those quotes did the trick - I get a successful response from the server!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution - perhaps not the most elegant, but it does the trick. Ended up using HTTP::Request::Common to get around the authorization issue and reversed the quoting on the JSON variable to mitigate the 400 Bad Request and success - getting a correct return from the server! Thanks for the help @steffen_ullrich.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use Data::Dumper;

my $fqdn_port = "<FQDN>:443";
my $url       = "<URL>";
my $realm     = "<REALM>";
my $username  = "<USERNAME>";
my $password  = "<PASSWORD>";
my $json      = '<JSON_CONTENT>';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 1 });
my $request = HTTP::Request->new('POST',$url);
$request->header('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept' => '*/*');
$request->authorization_basic($username,$password);
$request->content($json);

my $response = $ua->request($request);
print Dumper $response;
exit;


$VAR1 = bless( {
         '_protocol' => 'HTTP/1.1',
         '_content' => '<RETURN JSON FROM SERVER>',
         '_rc' => '200',
         '_headers' => bless( {
                    'connection' => 'close',
                    'client-response-num' => 1,
                    'date' => 'Mon, 16 May 2016 16:07:07 GMT',
                    'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => '[REDACTED]',
                    'client-ssl-cipher' => 'AES128-SHA256',
                    'client-peer' => '<SERVER_IP>:443',
                    'content-length' => '233',
                    '::std_case' => {
                              'client-date' => 'Client-Date',
                              'client-response-num' => 'Client-Response-Num',
                              'client-ssl-cert-subject' => 'Client-SSL-Cert-Subject',
                              'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => 'Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer',
                              'client-ssl-cipher' => 'Client-SSL-Cipher',
                              'client-peer' => 'Client-Peer',
                              'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'Client-SSL-Socket-Class'
                            },
                    'client-date' => 'Mon, 16 May 2016 16:07:07 GMT',
                    'content-type' => 'application/json',
                    'client-ssl-cert-subject' => '[REDACTED]',
                    'server' => 'Apache',
                    'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'IO::Socket::SSL'
                      }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
         '_msg' => 'OK',
         '_request' => bless( {
                    '_content' => '<JSON_CONTENT>',
                    '_uri' => bless( do{\(my $o = '<URL>')}, 'URI::https' ),
                    '_headers' => bless( {
                                   'user-agent' => 'libwww-perl/6.15',
                                   'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                   'accept' => '*/*',
                                   '::std_case' => {
                                         'if-ssl-cert-subject' => 'If-SSL-Cert-Subject'
                                           },
                                   'authorization' => 'Basic <BASE64-ENCODED USERNAME:PASSWORD>'
                                 }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
                    '_method' => 'POST',
                    '_uri_canonical' => $VAR1->{'_request'}{'_uri'}
                      }, 'HTTP::Request' )
           }, 'HTTP::Response' );
```

Comment: Updates to the question should be done as update to the question and **not as an answer**.